# Return from function even in if statements

Tags: javascript, function

Is there a way to return from a function even inside an if/else statement?

```
function test(){
   if (param){
      //code
      return
   }
   //code executes still executes (although I want to just stop the function entirely)
}
```

Comment: it should work. do you have an example where it does not work?

Comment: So I would guess it is not actually going into the if it still runs.... hard to guess

Comment: The only way the code gets executed after that return is if the return was never hit.

Comment: Are you sure the condition inside if is true?

Answer (score 0):

It should work, here's an example program that resembles what you asked

```js
function minusOne(n) {
  if (n === 0) {
    //returning in the if-statement
    return 0;
  }
  //continuing past if-statement
  return n - 1;
}

console.log(minusOne(4)) //output 3
console.log(minusOne(2)) //output 1
console.log(minusOne(0)) //output 0 (returns inside if statement)
console.log(minusOne(1)) //output 0
```

Comment: He just wanted to stop the function execution, your solution will always return a value.

Comment: I was just showing with a value how you would return in an if-statement as its easier to understand what’s going on. If you remove the value being returned, it works just as well.